# Java - Client-to-client communication with GUI. Return message issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to set up client-to-client communication, and I'm having some trouble.

Currently I'm having one act as a server and the other a client, and I'm struggling to get the server to send confirmation of the connection back to the client in the form of a simple text message in the GUI.

My code at the moment makes the client send a simple hello message to the server which works. The commented out code is my latest attempt to send a connection confirmation message back to the client, but it hasn't worked.

Here is the server code:

```
JMenuItem SeederItem = new JMenuItem("Seeder mode");
SeederItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        // Seeder mode

        try
        {
            // Waiting to be connected to
            System.out.println("Seeder waiting for leecher..");
            DatagramSocket SeederSocket = new DatagramSocket(2345);
            byte[] SeederBuffer = new byte[512];
            DatagramPacket DGP = new DatagramPacket(SeederBuffer,SeederBuffer.length);

            // Receiving connection attempt
            String message = "";
            SeederSocket.receive(DGP);
            message = new String(SeederBuffer);

            System.out.println(message);

            /*
            // Response to connection attempt
            String returnGreeting = "You have successfully connected to the seeder!";
            SeederBuffer = returnGreeting.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket DGPResponse = new DatagramPacket(SeederBuffer,SeederBuffer.length);
            SeederSocket.send(DGPResponse);
            */
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the client's code:

```
JButton btnConnect = new JButton("Connect to seeder");
btnConnect.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Attempting to connect
            InetAddress MyAddress = InetAddress.getByName(txtHostAddress.getText());
            DatagramSocket LeecherSocket = new DatagramSocket();

            String Greeting = "Hello from the leecher";
            byte[] LeecherBuffer = Greeting.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(LeecherBuffer,LeecherBuffer.length,MyAddress,Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText()));
            LeecherSocket.send(dp);

            System.out.println("Activation test");

            //????

            /*
            // Receiving successful connection response
            DatagramPacket DGPReceiveResponse = new DatagramPacket(LeecherBuffer,LeecherBuffer.length);

            String message = "";
            LeecherSocket.receive(DGPReceiveResponse);
            message = new String(LeecherBuffer);

            System.out.println(message);
            */
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SocketException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

If the commented out code is uncommented, it even breaks the code that sends the clients message from client to server. It returns this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: null address || null buffer –

It also mentions this issue:

> ClientFrame1$1.actionPerformed(ClientFrame1.java:83)`, which refers to this line:`SeederSocket.send(DGPResponse);

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The problem has already been solved, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an IP address on where the packet is going to. Like you did when you sent the first packet.  http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getAddress()

use this function from the DGP instance that was created when you did SeederSocket.recieve(DCP);

So:

```
String returnGreeting = "You have successfully connected to the seeder!";
                SeederBuffer = returnGreeting.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket DGPResponse = new DatagramPacket(SeederBuffer,SeederBuffer.length, DGP.getAddress(), DGP.getPort());
                SeederSocket.send(DGPResponse);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It solved my issue to the T ;)